# How do i open a Terminal with a command ready?

Tags: command-line, xfce

I really want to know this.
I don't always want to open a terminal then press Up arrow a couple of time or copy paste

Comment: Do you want the terminal to guess what you want to do?

Comment: You can use control + r to search commands.

Comment: No, I want it to be a specific line.

Comment: @Zanna
WINEPREFIX=~/.wineCustom/SteamBrawlhalla wine ~/Downloads/FILENAME

Comment: Don’t you want to [create a script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/787602/creating-a-bash-script) or an [alias](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias)?

Comment: @DavidFoerster This was indeed a dupe, Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can make a profile in Gnome terminal that automatically opens a script every time you open a Terminal.

Open a terminal and make a script in your home dir (ctrl-alt-t).

```
nano test
```

Enter your script, change the command and echo text to whatever you want

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "input syntax"
read command
#input command here instead of ls
ls "$command"
/bin/bash
```

save and exit. (ctrl-x, y)

Now open a terminal (ctrl-alt-t)
Select Edit --> Profile prefferences.

Select run a custom command:

[image: Custom Profile]

The next time you open a terminal it runs the script waiting for your input and finishes by opening bash.

[image: Terminal]