# Backup before shutdown?

Tags: shutdown, deja-dup

Deja Dup runs in the morning & hogs my CPU.
Is there a way to add a new button to the Ubuntu "power off" menu that will "backup then shut down" in addition to the 'shut down' buttons?

Comment: Alternative: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/880551/reduce-process-priority-of-built-in-deja-dup-duplicity-process-in-unity for how to assign Deja Dup a lower resource priority so your foreground tasks still get plenty of CPU and don't slow down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [create your own little script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/787602/creating-a-bash-script) that runs the backup program, then [shuts the computer down](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168879/shutdown-from-terminal-without-entering-password). If you then [create a `.desktop` launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79583/adding-custom-applications-to-gnome-launcher/79596#79596) for it and place that in `~/.local/share/applications`, then an icon for that script will appear in your applications overview. You could then start the backup and shut down from the applications overview.

Comment: Awesome plan. I put the script in an argos extension. so the button is right next to the power off on the header. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could inspire you. If this answer helped you, then please consider "accepting" it: click the checkmark next to the question.

Comment: Update. Got a different ext. https://github.com/PRATAP-KUMAR/Bring-Out-Submenu-of-Power-Off-Logout & then modified it to add a new button that runs a script "deja-dup --backup; shutdown". Right there in the power off menu like i wanted.